# Show the dropdown menu when hoverd for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Hi Consider the following code.when we hover on the button,the dropdown immediately shows up without any delay.if there anyway we can delay the appearance of dropdown menu.because we want to avoid the accidental hover on the menus.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use transition in css or you can achieve that by jquery/javascript timeout function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple pure CSS solution:

Use `opacity` instead of `display` and set `transition-delay` to `2s`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found an issue in your solution : **hover** over `Dropdown` (green button) and quickly move your cursor to the bottom of the green Dropdown button (i.e.; we are currently hovering over the green button), it should not show the dropdown menu, but it is showing.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>

<!-- importing jquery cdn -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function(){

      // creating hover event on html element with ".dropbtn" class

     $(".dropbtn").hover(function(){

      /* 
         show the html element with class ".dropdown-content" 
         after 2000 millisecond(2 second) 
       */

                     $(".dropdown-content").show(2000);
              },
                 function(){
             $(".dropdown-content").hover(function(){

            // show this(current) html element

                     $(this).show();
              },function(){
          /*
            hide  this(current) html element after 1000 millisecond
           (1second)
         */

                     $(this).hide(1000);
                });
           });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>



<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Full page
```

Comment: using CSS can be a little difficuilt  instead using jquery can solve the problem in a better way